# I'm downloading Minecraft for the first time. Will I need to buy anything?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is the first time I'm seeing Minecraft. I don't know what it is I've never played it. I saw a "Buy now" button but I didn't press it. I instead clicked on a button that said download and I started downloading the 270KB .exe file. Is there anything I will be missing out on by not buying the game???

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're not actually downloading Minecraft — you're downloading the official game launcher.

That launcher will, given valid log-in credentials (obtained by [signing up](http://www.minecraft.net/register) and [purchasing the game](http://www.minecraft.net/store)), download Minecraft and allow you to play it. So by not paying, you're missing out on the entire game, as it were.

Answer (score 10):

You can play a free version of Minecraft [here](http://www.minecraft.net/classic/play) so you can get the basic idea of the game. But beware, the current version offers so much more than this classic version that to really make up your mind you should have played the full version.

To name few things you are missing out:

1. [Crafting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Crafting) (huge part of the game)
2. [Redstone circuits](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits)
3. Survival mode (fight against mobs)
4. [Enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting)
5. [Alchemy](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alchemy)

There are certainly many more I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the demo of Minecraft.

The demo is a free version that lasts for 100 minutes, but with no creative mode, multiplayer or skin changing.

As always when downloading, make sure you're downloading from [**official sources only**](https://minecraft.net/), or you risk compromising the security of your computer.

You can purchase the full version for £17 - £20. It's good to use the demo first as it will allow you to determine whether or not your system can cope with the full version of the game, and it hasn't cost you any money to find out.

Answer (score 0):

The download will only gain you access to the launcher. The launcher can be used to play Minecraft but requires login details which you can only get by purchasing the game.

**You can play Minecraft for a limited time for free using PC Gamer's Demo and this demo includes all features which Minecraft includes.** [Click here](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/04/19/download-the-minecraft-demo/) to go to the download page. The demo includes things as [crafting](http://www.minecraft-crafting-guide.org/), survival mode and all the good stuff you find in the full Minecraft version.

Thought I'd point out the PC Gamer Demo as it's easily forgotten about.